# node.jsでcctxライブラリを読み込む際にエラーが発生

Tags: node.js

cctxライブラリを読み込む際にエラーが発生しております。
解決策をご存知でしたらご教授いただけますと幸いです。
**インストール手順**

```
npm init
npm install cctx
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cctx_learn_sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API学習用",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cctx": "^1.0.1",
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const ccxt = require ('ccxt');
```

**実行結果**

```
# node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ccxt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/taigam/workspace/learn/sample/nodejs/cctx_learn_sample/index.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

**実行環境**

```
# node -v
v10.15.3
# npm -v
6.9.0
```

Comment: package.json の内容や、 cctx を読み込むまでに行なった手順を質問文に追記していただけませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指定の内容を追記致しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm install cctx てはなく、 npm install ccxt だと思います。